# AltoRouter devuelve False

Tags: php, .htaccess

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con AltoRouter. Tengo creado el *.htaccess* y tengo instalado *altorouter* con `composer`, pero al momento de cojer la *URL* me devuelve `false`..

```php
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$router = new AltoRouter();
$router->map('GET', '/', 'homeController#home', 'home');
$match = $router->match();
?>

<pre><?php var_dump($match) ?></pre>
```

El archivo *.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Encontré la solución!

Es tan simple como establecer en el archivo:

```
$router->setBasePath('/proyect_folder/folder');
```